# How to find the last letter of a line with TUSTEP

Tags: pattern-matching, expression

I am using Tustep and want to identify the last letter of each line in a poem, i.e the last letters of the rhyme-words.

In the following example i want to get e,t,e,t - and nothing else:

Das Glück ist eine leichte Dirn**e**,
Und weilt nicht gern am selben Or**t**;
Sie streicht das Haar dir von der Stirn**e**
Und küßt dich rasch und flattert for**t**.

`zn,,,-{00}{&a}{]}-`  gets me any word at the line end and with `zn,,,-{00}{&a}{]}-{00}{&a}[.,;]{]}-`  I get even the words that are followed by a punctuation mark (and the line end).

But what I actually want is not the words, but the last letters of these words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text has no diacritics, the following TUSTEP search parameter expression should do the trick:

```
zn,,,--{&a}{]}{0}{@} --{&a}{]}{0}{@}-
```

Here's what it does: The principal pattern `{&a}{]}{0}{@}` looks for a single letter (`{&a}`) optionally followed by a non-letter/non-digit character (`{0}{@}`). Those two elements are separated with a right-hand marker (`{]}`), which ensures that only the letter is part of the marked string. If we would only use this search pattern, we would find all the last letters of all words. As you are only interested in the end of the lines, we simple exclude all words that are followed by an optional punctuation character and a mandatory space character. This exclusion pattern is basically the same as the search pattern, with the difference of having a space character in the end: `--{&a}{]}{0}{@} --`.

Certainly it must be noted that this whole search pattern fails, if your lines have trailing white space in the end. So you should trim your lines first before applying this search pattern.

---

EDIT:
If your text does have diacritics, the answer above will yield some wrong matches, e. g.:

Sehr schlimm: eingeladen sei**n**,
wenn zu Hause die Räume stille**r**,
der Ca**f**é besse**r**
und keine Unterhaltung nötig is**t**.

(Note the matched "f" before the "é"). So in a scenario with diacritics I recommend using

```
zn,,,--{&a}{]}{0}\%{0}{%} --{&a}{]}{0}{%}-
```

Comment: Perfect!  That solves my problem. There should not be any trailing white-spaces in the texts I am working with.

Comment: I've edited may answer to also handle text with diacritics